# How to get Selected Text from DIV

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the selected text from textarea but I can't get it from a div.
I'm trying with document.getElementById('myDiv') but it doesn't work.

To be more specific. When I have text, using this method I can get the selected text

```
function TestSelection () 
{
            if (window.getSelection) {  
                var selectionRange = window.getSelection(); 
                alert ("The text content of the selection:\n" + selectionRange.toString());
            }
}
```

but I cant specify the div to get it's selected text. Only from this div, not from another.
I tried `var value = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;`
and then `value.getSelection` but it doesn't work too.
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5379120/1066234

Answer (score 4):

Simply ,do the following :

```
var ss=getSelection();

ss.baseNode.data.substring(ss.baseOffset,ss.extentOffset);
```

[image]

Comment: If you use this code with marking a text by mouse and then releasing the mouse outside of the selected text, it returns an empty string.

Comment: remember the answer is 10 years old :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) property

```
var html = document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question to be more specific because I still can't do it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) property:

```
var value = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection)

```
var selObj = window.getSelection();
window.alert(selObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

for jquery

```
var str = $("#myDiv").text();
```

str is the text